# Selecting a value from Dynamic List of Values using Selenium and Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a website which displays a list of values. I need to select one value and scrape, followed by another selection. I am just unable to do this, after I save the page, I see the following code for the list of value:

```
<div class="dropdown-component spacing-left spacing-top">
<!-- ko component: { name: "dropdown-component", params: { value: categoryDropdown } } --><div class="btn-group" data-bind="attr: { &#39;data-id&#39;: id }" data-id="dropdown-component-118db170-aa45-43ac-94ee-8d78c72bda58">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-component clear" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-bind="event: { keydown: onKeyDown }">
        <div class="table-dropdown">
            <div class="text">
                <span data-bind="i18n: labelKey, visible: labelKey">Category</span>
                <span data-bind="text: seperator, visible: seperator &amp;&amp; selectedOptionHasText()">:</span>
                <!-- ko if: selectedText() -->
                <span data-bind="text: selectedText">All</span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: selectedTextKey() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <div class="icon caret"></div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-dropdown" data-bind="foreach: options, css: css">

        <li data-bind="css: { highlighted: !isCategory &amp;&amp; id === $parent.highlightedOption() }, event: { mouseenter: $parent.onMouseEnter, mouseout: $parent.onMouseOut }" class="">
            <!-- ko if: isNoType -->
            <a data-bind="text: text, click: $parent.action.bind($index), i18n: textKey, &#39;i18n-options&#39;: textKeyReplacements">All</a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: isCategory --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: isCategoryItem --><!-- /ko -->
        </li>

        <li data-bind="css: { highlighted: !isCategory &amp;&amp; id === $parent.highlightedOption() }, event: { mouseenter: $parent.onMouseEnter, mouseout: $parent.onMouseOut }" class="">
            <!-- ko if: isNoType -->
            <a data-bind="text: text, click: $parent.action.bind($index), i18n: textKey, &#39;i18n-options&#39;: textKeyReplacements">Not Classified</a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: isCategory --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: isCategoryItem --><!-- /ko -->
        </li>
```

It shows that the lov has a dynamic id assigned to it. Any idea how to select values from this lov? It has values like "All", "Not Classified" etc.

I have been able to resolve this by below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Category')]").click()
driver.execute(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Not Classofied')]").click())
```

This solves my issue, but I receive an error in python as: "KeyError: None".

I am not sure why this error comes, but for time being I am ignoring it by a try-except block.

Comment: can you share url of site?

Comment: @Dev: Sorry, I can't share the url. Its an internal company website

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium? Also, see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

In css you would get those with:

```
.dropdown-menu.scrollable-dropdown li a
```

Comment: I have somehow managed to resolve this issue, but still getting a minor problem. What I did was record the steps using Selenium addin to firefox. Managed to find the xpath to the lov:  "//span[contains(.,'Category')]". Then I use click function on it, which basically calls drop-down on the lov. Next, I use driver.execute as:   driver.execute(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Not Classified')]").click())   This works perfecly, but I still receive an error in python as:  "KeyError: None"

Comment: @Sarah, can you provide your latest code containing selenium code?